# Error with rabbit-mq server

Tags: rabbitmq, openstack, dpkg, devstack

I am trying to setup OpenStack on Ubuntu 12.04 using devstack. Now, the error I am getting is:

```
Setting up rabbitmq-server (2.7.1-0ubuntu4) ...
Starting rabbitmq-server: FAILED - check /var/log/rabbitmq/startup_{log, _err}
rabbitmq-server.
invoke-rc.d: initscript rabbitmq-server, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing rabbitmq-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 rabbitmq-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
++ err_trap
++ local r=100
++ set +o xtrace
stack.sh failed
```

Any idea why am I getting this error?

Comment: Have you looked into `/var/log/rabbitmq/startup_{log, _err}`

Comment: I did it just says rabbitmq failed to start!

Answer (score 20):

I had this issue twice, when either hostname or ip address in the hosts file didn't match.
Therefore, check that you provide the correct ip address and hostname in the /etc/hosts file

1. Run `sudo cat /etc/hostname` to see your hostname

Output:

```
yoursite
```

2. Run `sudo nano /etc/hosts`

File contains:

```
127.0.0.1 yoursite
```

As you see from cat /etc/hostname, hostname is the same as in the /etc/hosts:

3. Run `sudo rabbitmq-server start` to start the rabbitmq-server

Comment: In /etc/hosts the first line is `127.0.0.1 localhost`. It also needs to have the line `127.0.0.1 yoursite`? sorry for my english!

Comment: @EduardoPascualAseff Yes, each line is another link for reference by other prgrams

Comment: This helped solve after I upgraded the version

Answer (score 4):

Try deleting the folder /var/lib/rabbitmq and re-running ./stack.sh

If that doesn't work either, run the following after stach.sh fails:

chown -R rabbitmq:rabbitmq /var/lib/rabbitmq
chown -R rabbitmq:rabbitmq /var/log/rabbitmq

service rabbitmq-server restart

and check the status of rabbitmq using "rabbitmqctl status"

Answer (score 3):

Similar thing happen to me. Rabbit depends on being able to resolve a hostname, run this:

> echo "127.0.0.1 $(hostname -s)" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts

Answer (score 2):

This way works for me.
First go to

`sudo vim /etc/hosts`

and set

`127.0.0.1    <hostname>`

then open firewall

```
sudo rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
sudo service rabbitmq-server restart
```

Answer (score 0):

For a clean environment, this will not happen. You must run devstack for several times, and one of them failed but you didn't get it cleaned.

run command `pf -ef | grep rabbitmq`, kill all rabbitmq processes. then it would be fine to run `./stack.sh`

it is highly recommended to run `./unstack.sh && ./clean.sh` before `./stack.sh`

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure, take a look to your local network

```
ip add
```

If there's no `lo` network, then you should enable it:

```
ifconfig lo up
```

Then restart the server again and let's see if it works again now

```
systemctl start rabbitmq-server
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem though my `/etc/hosts` and DNS were OK. I suspect that SystemV init script was started too early when the network was not ready yet. I rewrote the startup script to `systemd` on CentOS 7.8 and it seems to work well now.

```
[Unit]
Description=RabbitMQ
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
RuntimeDirectory=rabbitmq
PrivateTmp=true
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10

WorkingDirectory=/opt/data/rabbitmq/
User=rabbitmq
Group=rabbitmq

ExecStart=/opt/app/rabbitmq/default/sbin/rabbitmq-server
ExecStop=/opt/app/rabbitmq/default/sbin/rabbitmqctl stop
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c "while ps -p $MAINPID >/dev/null 2>&1; do sleep 1; done"

StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=inherit

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```