# Rabbit MQL is not starting

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang

I've installed and am trying to run rabbitmql, but it's not starting, and is instead throwing the error shown below. I tried applying the advice from the following answers, but they didn't help:

- [Keep the hostname and server IP names the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23106813/error-with-rabbit-mq-server)
- [Delete mnesia files due to possible corruption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25619201/rabbitmq-start-fails)

```
              RabbitMQ 3.6.10. Copyright (C) 2007-2017 Pivotal Software, Inc.
  ##  ##      Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/
  ##  ##
  ##########  Logs: /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@vishruth.log
  ######  ##        /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@vishruth-sasl.log
  ##########
              Starting broker...


BOOT FAILED
===========

Error description:
   {could_not_start,rabbit,
       {{case_clause,
            {error,
                {{shutdown,
                     {failed_to_start_child,
                         {ranch_listener_sup,
                             {acceptor,{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},5672}},
                         {shutdown,
                             {failed_to_start_child,ranch_acceptors_sup,
                                 {listen_error,
                                     {acceptor,{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},5672},
                                     eaddrinuse}}}}},
                 {child,undefined,'rabbit_tcp_listener_sup_:::5672',
                     {tcp_listener_sup,start_link,
                         [{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                          5672,ranch_tcp,
                          [inet6,
                           {backlog,128},
                           {nodelay,true},
                           {linger,{true,0}},
                           {exit_on_close,false}],
                          rabbit_connection_sup,[],
                          {rabbit_networking,tcp_listener_started,
                              [amqp,
                               [{backlog,128},
                                {nodelay,true},
                                {linger,{true,0}},
                                {exit_on_close,false}]]},
                          {rabbit_networking,tcp_listener_stopped,
                              [amqp,
                               [{backlog,128},
                                {nodelay,true},
                                {linger,{true,0}},
                                {exit_on_close,false}]]},
                          10,"TCP Listener"]},
                     transient,infinity,supervisor,
                     [tcp_listener_sup]}}}},
        [{rabbit_networking,start_listener0,5,
             [{file,"src/rabbit_networking.erl"},{line,225}]},
         {rabbit_networking,'-start_listener/5-lc$^0/1-0-',5,
             [{file,"src/rabbit_networking.erl"},{line,213}]},
         {rabbit_networking,start_listener,5,
             [{file,"src/rabbit_networking.erl"},{line,213}]},
         {rabbit_networking,'-boot_tcp/1-lc$^0/1-0-',2,
             [{file,"src/rabbit_networking.erl"},{line,126}]},
         {rabbit_networking,boot_tcp,1,
             [{file,"src/rabbit_networking.erl"},{line,126}]},
         {rabbit_networking,boot,0,
             [{file,"src/rabbit_networking.erl"},{line,121}]},
         {rabbit_boot_steps,'-run_step/2-lc$^1/1-1-',1,
             [{file,"src/rabbit_boot_steps.erl"},{line,49}]},
         {rabbit_boot_steps,run_step,2,
             [{file,"src/rabbit_boot_steps.erl"},{line,49}]}]}}

Log files (may contain more information):
   /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@vishruth.log
   /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@vishruth-sasl.log

{"init terminating in do_boot",{could_not_start,rabbit,{{case_clause,{error,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,{ranch_listener_sup,{acceptor,{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},5672}},{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,ranch_acceptors_sup,{listen_error,{acceptor,{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},5672},eaddrinuse}}}}},{child,undefined,'rabbit_tcp_listener_sup_:::5672',{tcp_listener_sup,start_link,[{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},5672,ranch_tcp,[inet6,{backlog,128},{nodelay,true},{linger,{true,0}},{exit_on_close,false}],rabbit_connection_sup,[],{rabbit_networking,tcp_listener_started,[amqp,[{backlog,128},{nodelay,true},{linger,{true,0}},{exit_on_close,false}]]},{rabbit_networking,tcp_listener_stopped,[amqp,[{backlog,128},{nodelay,true},{linger,{true,0}},{exit_on_close,false}]]},10,"TCP Listener"]},transient,infinity,supervisor,[tcp_listener_sup]}}}},[{rabbit_networking,start_listener0,5,[{file,"src/rabbit_networking.erl"},{line,225}]},{rabbit_networking,'-start_listener/5-lc$^0/1-0-',5,[{file,"src/rabbit_networking.erl"},{line,213}]},{rabbit_networking,start_listener,5,[{file,"src/rabbit_networking.erl"},{line,213}]},{rabbit_networking,'-boot_tcp/1-lc$^0/1-0-',2,[{file,"src/rabbit_networking.erl"},{line,126}]},{rabbit_networking,boot_tcp,1,[{file,"src/rabbit_networking.erl"},{line,126}]},{rabbit_networking,boot,0,[{file,"src/rabbit_networking.erl"},{line,121}]},{rabbit_boot_steps,'-run_step/2-lc$^1/1-1-',1,[{file,"src/rabbit_boot_steps.erl"},{line,49}]},{rabbit_boot_steps,run_step,2,[{file,"src/rabbit_boot_steps.erl"},{line,49}]}]}}}
init terminating in do_boot ({could_not_start,rabbit,{{case_clause,{error,{_}}},[{rabbit_networking,start_listener0,5,[_]},{rabbit_networking,-start_listener/5-lc$^0/1-0-,5,[_]},{rabbit_networking,sta
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that RabbitMQ cannot listen in the configured ipv6 interface:  `{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},5672},eaddrinuse`

Comment: okay,please can you tell me how to solve this?Sorry for my English,I started an year ago and i am working on my grammer.

Comment: @Anil The :: ipv6 means "listen in all ipv6 interfaces", and this is the one you are having issues with. Either you have another process listening in that interface or that interface is not available at all. First, I'd opt to disable listening in it from config to check that this is indeed the issue. You have configuration examples in [RabbitMQ networking doc](https://www.rabbitmq.com/networking.html#single-stack-ipv4)

Comment: @Anil also, you can check which process is listening under UNIX with the netstat command: ` sudo netstat -punta | grep 5672 `